# Getting error while setting up linting for Vue.js library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, installation, eslint

I'm trying to setup linting in my project. I was referring this link (https://habr.com/en/post/436176/) for the same. When I run npm run lint it executes and shows me some error but later on it throws me an error. I'm not sure if its the right process or not. Can anybody help me setting up linting for my vuejs project.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked in the log file?

Comment: Have you tried to run npm run lint --fix ?

I think this is kind of expected as there are errors. --fix should automatically fix them for you.